# Getting running timer using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I got a span that is a timer, where time keep going on. Using selenium I want to grab the current timer value.

```
<div id="dealTimeRemaining" class="miniText marginTop green">
  <span id="cdf8882c_time_remaining">
     <span class="ticker">00</span>h 
     <span class="ticker">46</span>m 
     <span class="ticker">22</span>s 
  </span>
</div>
```

But the point is the spans with class ticker, keeps on changing, so how to get the value when I run my selenium project.

Also, the id "cdf8882c_time_remaining" is dynamic, so please don't hard code it. Rest all is fine.

Comment: post the url, there may need to use js execution!

Comment: Kindly show what you have tried so far. Please do not expect the community to do your work

Comment: @SIslam Its http://www.amazon.com/b?node=11448061011 , for deals going on, I want the ending time left

Comment: @Striker This is not any homework.

Comment: @Striker I tried stopping this javascript with selenium. But wasn't able to succedd

Comment: The down votes is because of the point I said. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `span` element located inside the `div` with `id="dealTimeRemaining"`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#dealTimeRemaining > span")).getText();
```

Comment: This won't return it because its been feed by javascript . See the link i provided under blockbuster deals

Comment: This will return the updated time just when the code ran- if you want next update then run again hah!

Comment: @SIslam This is not giving . I checked. Had you checked the link I attached ? The "Ends in xx h yy m zz s" is returning just "End in" with this statement

Comment: @GitCoder the locator itself is correct and matches the provided in the question element. I am pretty sure you just need to wait for the timer to be started with `WebDriverWait`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. U can get page source and pass it through a html parsers like `jsoup`.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/b?node=11448061011");

String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

// parse the page source through jsoup
Document document = Jsoup.parse(pageSource);

// get all the elements containing id dealTimeRemaining
Elements dealTimeRemainingDivs = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "dealTimeRemaining");

// iterate through all the deal time remaining divs
for (Element dealTimeRemainingDiv : dealTimeRemainingDivs) {
    String time = "Time";
    // find the ticker spans containing the time
    Elements tickerSpans = dealTimeRemainingDiv.getElementsByClass("ticker");
    // iterate through all the ticker spans
    for (Element tickerSpan : tickerSpans) {
        time = time + ":" + tickerSpan.text();
    }
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Output

```
Time:09:23:44
Time:09:23:43
Time:09:23:43
Time:09:23:43
Time:00:08:44
Time:03:28:44
Time:00:03:44
Time:08:53:44
```